# how to set default value for a field in Sails models using Waterline ORM?

Tags: sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

A very simple question but I am unable to find the answer to it.
So in my Sails app I have a User model and I am trying to make a boolean field with a default value to be False.

Is there a way to specify defaults like some kind of default attribute etc??

I want something like this:

```
is_admin: {
        type: 'boolean',
        default: 'false'
    }
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

use `defaultsTo`
look this [Waterline Docs](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models/models.md)

Comment: Be careful! In Mongo the default value is not set on objects older than the field it added a default value.
For example if you added a 'locale' field to user model, after you already had some users, the old users will not be added a default locale value. only new users will have it.

Answer (score 5):

To use a contextual example of "defaultsTo" as described in Zieglar's answer

```
is_admin : {
    type : "boolean",
    defaultsTo : false
}
```